# Not able to import scripts inside service_worker js in chrome extension manifest version 3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I had multiple background scripts in chrome extension manifest version 2.
Now I need to migrate to manifest version 3 and therefore need to make necessary changes.

According to documentation, I have kept only one file in service_worker as shown below:

```
"background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
},
```

and in the background.js I wrote the following javascript statement:

```
try {
importScripts('js/google-analytics.js', 'js/google-analytics-bundle.js', 'js/eventSender.js', 'js/api-gsc.js', 'js/api-sm.js', 'js/lib/jquery.js');
} catch (e) {
console.error(e);
}
```

The code in google-analytics.js has the following code:

```
window.onload = startApp;
```

Also, inside background.js I am using `localStorage`.

When I try to load the extension, it gives me the following errors:

```
background.js:16 ReferenceError: window is not defined
at google-analytics.js:23
at background.js:14

Error in event handler: ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
at chrome-extension://<ExtensionId>/background.js:99:28

TypeError: Cannot read property 'createElement' of undefined
at ja (jquery.js:2)
at jquery.js:2
at jquery.js:2
at jquery.js:2
at jquery.js:2
at background.js:14

Error handling response: ReferenceError: XMLHttpRequest is not defined
at getUserStatus (chrome-extension://<extensionId>/js/api-gsc.js:9:19)
at chrome-extension://<ExtensionId>/background.js:112:17
```

and many other errors also.

It seems like it is not able to import the javaScript files properly.

It might be alot to ask in a single question. But, can someone please help me where I am putting wrong code and if someone please help me with the solution.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The background script is a service worker so it doesn't have `window` or `localStorage`. You can't use these scripts there.

Answer (score 0):

try use `fetch()` replace `XMLHttpRequest`

I think you can find answer in this page [Cross-origin XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/xhr/)

Answer (score 0):

For importing scripts in background js you need to bundle it seperate from the main app with imports specific to each if you are using vite as a bundler then you can add a package called as crxjs to manage content and background scripts

##### Follow the below steps to get your backgroud script running in vite

1.Add crxjs to your project

`npm install @crxjs/vite-plugin -D`

2.Add background js/ts

```js
import xyz from "xyz"
// you can use package now 
console.log(xyz)
```

3.Create or update manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "CRXJS React Vite Example",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "action": { "default_popup": "index.html" },
  "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js",
        "type": "module"
    },
}
```

4.Update your vite.config.ts file with path to manifest

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import { crx } from '@crxjs/vite-plugin'
import manifest from './manifest.json'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    crx({ manifest }),
  ],
})
```

After this run your project , now config.js will be bundled and you can import packages in it

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the service worker context is completely separate from the main browser context so a window is not an option there.
You can use the `chrome.tabs` api to access to dom
And the same for the local storage use `chrome.storage`